# logic:iterate comparing the next value

Tags: struts

I am trying to perform a comparison to the current submission to the next.  I have the following code:

```
<logic:iterate id="anItem" name="dataPage" property="filingsList" 
    indexId="myInd">
    <bean:define id="currentSubmissionId" type="java.lang.String" 
    name="anItem" property="denseRank"/>
```

I would like to do something like:

```
<logic:equal name="dataPage" property="currentSubmissionId"
 value="nextSubmissionId???">

    <img id="plus<%=rowCount%>" class="cursor" 
       src="<icis2:icisRes/>images/plus.gif" 
       onclick="toggle('<%=rowCount%>', this, 
       jQuery('#minus<%=rowCount%>'))"/>

    <img id="minus<%=rowCount%>" class="cursor" 
       src="<icis2:icisRes/>images/minus.gif" onclick="toggle('<%=rowCount%>', 
       this, jQuery('#plus<%=rowCount%>'))" style="display: none;"/>
</logic:equal>
```

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: I have not used struts yet, but can help you with the logic. What do you do after comparing? Store the larger number or the smaller?

Comment: I want to compare the current submission to the next one, if they are the same print those two lines.

Comment: So how are you storing it? As String?

Comment: Also, do you only want to compare the 2 Consecutive submissions?

Comment: Yes the submission id is a string.  I want to compare just the current and the next one and if they match print the two lines of code, else do nothing.

Comment: Hey Tom, was wondering did the answer help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1. Create a temp string variable to "",
2. Store the current String here
3. Iterate, and compare. 
4. As you iterate check if equal or not. 
5. If equal print else copy next string to the variable.
```

Here is the code.

```
    String[] someArrayOfStrings;  // Store the Strings here. You can use ArrayList too.
    String tempString = "";       // Recommend to use ArrayList.

    for(int count=0; count<someArrayOfStrings.length-1; count++){
       tempString = someArrayOfStrings[count];

       if(tempString.equalsIgnoreCase(someArrayOfStrings[count+1])){
            System.out.print(tempString);    
        }
    }
```

Let me know if it helped.